# Solve the recurrence and verify the formula using strong induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, recurrence-relations

Let $a_n$ defined recursively by $a_0$ = 2, $a_1 = 4$ and

$a_{n+1}$ = 4$a_n$ - 3$a_{n-1}$, n $\ge$ 1

Solve the recurrence relation and verify the formula by using strong induction.

Attempt (not sure if it's right):

$\Rightarrow a_{n+1} - 4a_n + 3a_{n-1} = 0 \Rightarrow a^{n+1} - 4a^n + 3a^{n-1}$ = 0

$\Rightarrow a^2 - 4a + 3 = 0 \Rightarrow (a - 3)(a - 1) = 0 \Rightarrow a$ = 3,1

$\Rightarrow a_0 = 2 = B(3^n) + C = B + C$ = 2

$\Rightarrow a_1 = 4 = B(3^n) + C = 3B + C = 4$
$\Rightarrow B = 1, C = 1$

$\Rightarrow$ General formula: $a_n = 3^n + 1^n$

Hypothesis would be $ n > 1$ and $a_k \ge K$ for integers K such that $1 \le K < n$ ?

Not sure what to do next or if I was right up to this point

**Edit (added another question)**

$a_n = 5a_{n-1} - 6a_{n-2}, r_0=0$ and $r_1=1$

General formula $a_n= 3^n - 2^n$

Let us assume for some $n \ge 0, a_{n-1} = 3^{n-1} - 2^{n-1}$ and $a_{n-2} = 3^{n-2} - 2^{n-2}$ **Is this the right hypothesis?**

Thanks

Comment: The general formula is correct. First show it for $n=1$ and $n=2$. Then, show that the formula is correct for $a_{n+2}$, if it is correct for $a_{n+1}$ and $a_n$

Comment: Can I check for $a_{n-1}$, $a_{n-2}$, and prove $a_{n+1}$ ? Like in the hypothesis above? Not sure if it makes any difference.

Comment: Not quite, you have to ASSUME that the claim holds for $a_{n-2}$ and $a_{n-1}$ and to prove it for $a_n$. The base case consists of showing the claim for $n=1$ and $n=2$

Comment: Why prove $a_n$? if I prove $a_{n+1}$ then I have proved $a_n$ as well, no? btw, is my hypothesis above correct? :)

Comment: No, in this case you would leave a gap. The idea is simple : Suppose, the claim is true for $n=1$ and $n=2$. If we have proven the step from $n-1$ and $n-2$ to $n$, we can conclude that the claim is true for $n=3$. Using $n=2$ and $n=3$, we can conclude the case $n=4$ and so on. But if you go from $n-2$ and $n-1$ to $n+1$, you do not show the case $n$. Your hypothesis is correct. So, just plug-in those formulas in the recursion-formula and you should get $3^n-2^n$

Comment: Ok, let me try again (sorry for being annoying). Hypothesis: Let us assume for some $n \ge 0$, $a_n = 3^n - 2^n$ and $a_{n-1} = 3^{n-1} - 2^{n-1}$ and prove $a_{n+1}$ which means $a_{n+1} = a_n - a_{n-1}$?

Comment: This is OK as well!

Comment: Ok, I get it now. Thank you and all best to you Peter!

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is right, you did find the series. However, your redaction and reasoning are both terrible.

What you just wrote should not be on an answer. It is a draft that enables you to get the formula.

Once you have it, you can write the following.

$a_0=3^0+1$ and $a_1=3^1+1$. Let us assume that for some $n\geq 1$, $a_n=3^n+1$ and $a_{n-1}=3^{n-1}+1$. Let us calculate $a_{n+1}$

$a_{n+1} = 4(3^n+1)-3(3^{n-1}+1)=3^{n+1}+1$ (*What a surprise! I didn't expect this at all...*)

So by induction, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, a_n=3^n+1$

This kind of reasoning can be disturbing at first. But it is one valid way to proove your result. The disturbing fact is that the formula looks like it comes out of nowhere, you just tried formulas all day long and found one that fits. It is correct redaction, though.

Your implications do not prove anything. The first one (where you go from $a_n$ to $a^n$ somehow) is wrong, unless you assume some specific form for $a_n$ (and in this case you should change your notations).

Even if you had only valid implications to some property $A$, it would only show that any such sequence must verify property $A$, not that all sequences that verify property $A$ are solutions to your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help and criticism. I should have added $a_n=r_n(a!=0)$
and went from there, sufficient? For the strong induction I still don't quite grasp it. I have posted(edited) another question, please have a look at it. Thank!

Comment: Vincent do you have proof that the reasoning is wrong?I'm 95% sure that the reasoning here is sound.The wikipedia agrees that this is the way to solve this kind of reccurence relations https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients

Comment: It is the way to solve it, but not the way to prove that this is a solution.